# ES6 Class problems

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am new to classes in ECMA 6. I have two classes - my `App.js` and a simple `Image.js` class.
I am trying to create an empty `div` in `App.js`, and pass that div id to the image class to attach an img src.
It seems to fail at `document.getElementbyID` in `Image.js`

Any thoughts?

App.js

```
 class KK_App{

        constructor(src, width, height){

            this._imgdiv = document.createElement('div');
            this._imgdiv.setAttribute('id', 'posterphoto');

            var newpic = new KK_Image('poster_outlines2.png', 240, 250, this._imgdiv);
            newpic.draw();

        }

    }
```

KK_Image.js

```
class KK_Image{

    constructor(src, width, height, parent){
        this._src = src;
        this._width = width;
        this._height = height;
        this._parent = parent;
        this._parentid = this._parent.getAttribute('id');
    }

    draw(){
        console.log( this._parentid );
        const markup = `<img src='${this._src}' width='${this._width}' height='${this._height}'></img>`;
        document.getElementById(${this._parentid}).innerHTML = markup;

         //it dies here saying ${this._parentid} is null
         //it works if I pass the id of a div that is already loaded into the dom in html

    }

}
```

Comment: `it works if I pass the id of a div that is already loaded into the dom` - That's how `getElementById` works, it can't get what's not in the DOM. Please see the [**getElementById Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) for more details.

Comment: your element is only created, but not in the page, you need to append it

Comment: Why not create the image as an actual element, then just append it to the div using the DOM *appendChild* method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you create only element but don't add it anywhere. In `KK_App` you create new element and assign to instance property. Then in class `KK_Image` you expect, that document will have your element - this assumption is wrong, because you have never added that element to document.

To do so, you have to use for example `appendChild` function.

Proper solution should look like:

```
class KK_App{
    constructor(src, width, height){

        this._imgdiv = document.createElement('div');
        this._imgdiv.setAttribute('id', 'posterphoto');
        document.body.appendChild(this._imgdiv); // <- HERE
        var newpic = new KK_Image('poster_outlines2.png', 240, 250, this._imgdiv);
        newpic.draw();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `this._imgdiv = document.createElement('div');` - this only creates an element.

You need to also append it to your page, e.g:

```
document.body.appendChild(this._imgdiv)
```

When you do `document.getElementById(...` the element must be in the page to be found.